# Sonar maven plugin failing after upgrade to version 4.3.2

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I upgraded my sonar version from 3.7 to 4.3.2. I understand from the release notes that alerts have been replaced with quality gates concept and when I log in to the dashboard, I do not see any quality profile that I had created before. I created a quality gate and set that as the default one.

On executing sonar from maven using sonar maven plugin, I get the following error - You must install a plugin that supports the language 'java'. I use the jacoco plugin to get multi module code coverage.

Is there any change that I need to do in my POM to get it running again?

Comment: Hi, you forgot to copy plugins before starting server (see upgrade instructions)

Comment: Yes this fixed the issue thank you - can you please post as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when installed plugins (directory extensions/plugins) are not copied before upgrading. Error logs will be improved in next versions.